# Trying to set number as text in EditText

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having trouble setting a double in an edittext and I cannot get rid of the error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have:

```
    final EditText somedouble_et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.somedouble_search);
    somedouble_et.setText(doubleNumber.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

The error I am getting is that is doesn't recognize TextView as a class. Is there an error in my xml?

```
<EditText android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/somedouble"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:hint = ""
    android:text = "@+id/somedouble_search"/>
```

It does not seem to matter what id I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the first line of your code not be

```
final EditText somedouble_et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.somedouble);
```

and in the xml, android:text should not be "@+id" anything!

Make sure you have imported TextView at the top of your code.

Comment: I still get the same error when I delete this line: android:text = "@+id/somedouble_search"

Comment: Just a thought from the error message, have you imported TextView at the top of your code? Also make sure findViewById is looking for the same id as you've set your EditText to in the xml.

Comment: normally I am used to having "import android.widget.TextView;" automatically as an option, but writing it in directly, basically solved my problem.

Comment: Excellent! By the way, pressing Ctrl + Shift + "O" in eclipse will automatically import everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, the android:id field should be as follows:

```
android:id="@+id/somedouble_search"
```

The text field should either be hardcoded ("mytext") or refer to a string resource (@string/mystringresource).

**Hardcoded**

```
android:text = "Hardcoded text"
```

**Referencing something from strings.xml**

```
android:text="@string/mystringresource"
```

The following piece of code is searching for an EditText with the id of somedouble_search in your XML file, yet your id is defined as android:id="@+id/somedouble"

```
final EditText somedouble_et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.somedouble_search);
```

***Remember***

To reference any object defined in an XML, you reference it by its id defined in the xml - NOT by its text attribute. The text attribute only defines what text should be displayed.

For reference, please see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) link.

Comment: so if I am trying so initially set the text from a number in my java class, would I not include the android:text field?

Comment: Not include it in the xml? I think you can leave it out if it should have no value.